# How to merge work from detached state

Tags: git, branch

I was working on a git branch called `feature-branch` when I realized that I had introduced some bugs at some unknown commit in the past. I worked back through my commits and found the commit where the error was introduced. I checked out this commit, `277be1c` and fixed the bug, and would now like to stage and merge this work back onto `feature-branch`.

How can I do this? Do I use cherrypick? I am not sure how I should go about staging and committing this work which is in a detached head state back onto my feature branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a branch where you are now, then merge that new branch back into `feature-branch`.

The message that appears when you enter `detached HEAD state` includes this instruction for just your scenario:

> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
>   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
>
> git checkout -b new_branch_name